# where is LD_LIBRARY_PATH first set in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: bash, desktop-environments, bashrc

In my current account in ubuntu 20.04, when I print the value of $LD_LIBRARY_PATH at the start of .bashrc, I find it's been already set to '/usr/local/lib:'. It's not a big problem but the problem is that I want to remove that ':' at the end but can't remove it because I don't know  where it was first set. I checked ~/.profile, /etc/environment, and files under /etc/profile.d but no file had set the value. Where is it set first time?

Comment: AFAIK it's not set at all by default, so where it is "first set" will be specific to your system

Comment: Check out what's in /usr/local/lib, that might give you a clue what's setting it.